# how to highlight multiple rows in a table view using objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

If I touch first row, it will get highlighted. If I touch second row, first row highlighting is not there and second row is highlighted in table view of iOS. **I want to highlight (multiple) both rows**.

> Here is my Code

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

UIView *selectionColor = [[UIView alloc] init];
selectionColor.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
cell.selectedBackgroundView = selectionColor;

}
```

Comment: you can do like if(indexpath.row==1){Set COlor as per need} else if (indexpath.row==2){Set Color}

Comment: @Mehul I want to highlight both rows with same colour. If i touch row, following method will be called    "- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath "   Is there any way to do in this method?

Comment: Do NOT add a UIView sub view to the cell each time cellForRowAtIndexPath: is called! Cell instances get reused, and so you're needlessly replacing background view instances repeatedly. Just set the cell's background color instead of using a selectedBackgroundView.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
self.tableView.allowsMultipleSelection = YES;
```

property of UITableView.